# Clickable RSS Feed Python

Tags: python, rss

I installed a desktop conky widget for my Ubuntu and it has a feedparser for Python that delivers an RSS feed for Google news headlines, however these headlines are not clickable and I was wondering if it were possible to make them clickable so I could go to the headline simply by clicking it on my desktop? I have tried learning python, but the course I did was so terrible that I couldn't bear finishing so I am relatively unskilled in this area. Anyway heres the code:

```
import feedparser
rss_url = "http://news.google.com/?output=rss"
feed = feedparser.parse( rss_url )
count =  len(feed['entries'])
for i in range(0, count):
   if (i>=10):break
   print '{1}'.format(' ', feed.entries[i].title[0:100].encode('utf8'))
```

Thanks in advance
`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no real way to make a dynamic conky clickable. There are some ways to add buttons in static places detailed [here](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=18419), but only with conky's lua extensions.